# Toggle Classes with delays

Tags: jquery, toggle, block

I have 4 blocks and I want script to add classes with a delay: appears 1 block, then 2nd and so on. here is the code:

```
$(‘#about’).click(function() {
    $(‘.front’).toggleClass(‘open-front’);
    $(‘.back’).toggleClass(‘open-back’);
});
```

Before:

[image: Before]

...and After:

[After http://eyes.in.ua/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/question-2.png](http://eyes.in.ua/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/question-2.png)

See this color block that after click becomes black. They are four. But I want 1 block appear 1st, then the delay 600ms and script adds classes to 2nd block, then delay 1200ms and script adds to 3rd block classes. Thats what I want.

Pardon me, if I didn't explain it correctly...

Got any ideas?

Comment: i have some doubt that your quotation marks (`‘` and `’`) will work, but i might be mistaken...

Comment: oh. its working... it is shown wrong here.  Its in ' '.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
$('#about').click(function() {
    $('.front').toggleClass('open-front');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.back').toggleClass('open-back');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.third').toggleClass('open-third');
        }, 600);
    }, 600);
});
```

---

Or something like this?

```
$('#about').click(function() {
    var delay = 600;
    $('.front').each(function(i, e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(e).toggleClass('open-front');
        }, i * delay);
    });
    $('.back').each(function(i, e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(e).toggleClass('open-back');
        }, i * delay);
    });
});
```

Comment: for better understanding <a href=http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/RNrgoN>this is code</a>. But it looks dummy when it rotates at the same time. Need to rotate each block with a delay, for example 1st block opens, then 600ms opens 2nd one and so one...

Comment: Updated my answer. I think you mean this. Updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYKoJV

Comment: It is PERFECT! Thanks... if it means a thing. Great exp!